# C#, WPF-application, many tcpclients connect a tcplistener(server)

Tags: c#, wpf, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

**TcpServer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    public class TcpServer
    {
        static ServerGUI serverGUI;

        private const Int32 PORT = 13000;

        private const String ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";

        private IPAddress localAddress;

        public TcpListener tcpServer;

        private static Byte[] bytes;

        private static String data;

        static DateTime localDate;
        static String cultureName = "de-DE";
        static CultureInfo cultureInfo;

        private static int clientCount = 0;

        private const char SEPERATOR = '|';

        static NetworkStream stream;

        public TcpServer()
        {
            serverGUI = new ServerGUI();
            serverGUI.Show();

            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

            BackgroundWorker worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker1_DoWork);
            worker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serverGUI.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, (ThreadStart)(async delegate ()
                {
                    localAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ADDRESS);
                    tcpServer = new TcpListener(localAddress, PORT);
                    localDate = DateTime.Now;
                    serverGUI.AddOutput("(" + localDate.ToString("g", cultureInfo) + ") chatserver has started.\n");
                    tcpServer.Start();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        TcpClient client = await tcpServer.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
                    }

                }));
            }
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                serverGUI.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)(delegate ()
                {
                    serverGUI.AddOutput(socketEx.Message + "\n");
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                serverGUI.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)(delegate ()
                {
                    serverGUI.AddOutput(ex.Message + "\n");
                }));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (tcpServer != null)
                {
                    tcpServer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
        private static async void ThreadProc(object obj)
        {
            await serverGUI.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)(async delegate ()
             {
                 var client = (TcpClient)obj;
                 bytes = new Byte[256];
                 data = null;
                 // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                 stream = client.GetStream();

                 int i = 0;

                 while (true)
                 {
                     if (stream.CanRead)
                     {
                         i = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                     }
                     localDate = DateTime.Now;

                     data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                     string[] receivedStr = data.Split(SEPERATOR);
                     byte[] msg = null;
                     if (receivedStr != null && receivedStr[0] == "new")
                     {
                         clientCount++;

                         msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("chatserver" + SEPERATOR + "Welcome, " + receivedStr[2] + "! - active users: " + clientCount);

                         if (stream.CanWrite)
                         {
                             await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                         }


                         serverGUI.AddOutput("(" + localDate.ToString("g", cultureInfo) + ") new client recognized!\n");
                         serverGUI.AddOutput("                   " + receivedStr[1] + " - Nickname: " + receivedStr[2] + "\n");
                         serverGUI.AddOutput("                   " + "active clients: " + clientCount + "\n\n");
                     }
                     else if (receivedStr != null && receivedStr[0] == "close")
                     {
                         clientCount--;

                         msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("chatserver" + SEPERATOR + "Goodbye, " + receivedStr[2] + "! - active users: " + clientCount);

                         if (stream.CanWrite)
                         {
                             await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                         }

                         serverGUI.AddOutput("(" + localDate.ToString("g", cultureInfo) + ") client disconnected!\n");
                         serverGUI.AddOutput("                   " + receivedStr[1] + " - Nickname: " + receivedStr[2] + "\n");
                         serverGUI.AddOutput("                   " + "active clients: " + clientCount + "\n\n");

                         client.Close();
                         break;
                     }
                     else
                     {

                         msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                         if (stream.CanWrite)
                         {
                             await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }));
        }
    }
}
```

**(Client)MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Int32 port = 13000;

        private String hostname = "127.0.0.1";

        public TcpClient tcpClient;

        DateTime localDate;
        String cultureName = "de-DE";
        CultureInfo cultureInfo;

        BackgroundWorker worker1;
        NetworkStream stream;
        bool work = false;

        private const char SEPERATOR = '|';

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buttonDisconnect.IsEnabled = false;
            textBoxServerIP.Text = "127.0.0.1:13000";
            textBoxNickname.Text = "User";

            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

            worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker1.DoWork += Worker1_DoWork;
        }

        private void Worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, (ThreadStart)(async delegate ()
            {
                try
                {
                    while (work)
                    {

                        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hallo");

                        data = new Byte[256];

                        // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                        String responseData = String.Empty;

                        // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                        Int32 bytes = 0;
                        if (stream.CanRead)
                        {
                            bytes = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                        }


                        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                        string[] receivedStr = responseData.Split(SEPERATOR);

                        if (receivedStr != null && receivedStr[0] == "chatserver")
                        {
                            textBoxChatRoom.Text += receivedStr[0] + " (" + localDate.ToString("g", cultureInfo) + "): " + receivedStr[1] + "\n\n";
                        }
                        else if (receivedStr != null && receivedStr[0] == "msg")
                        {
                            textBoxChatRoom.Text += receivedStr[1] + " (" + localDate.ToString("g", cultureInfo) + "): " + receivedStr[2] + "\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textBoxChatRoom.Text += responseData + "\n\n";
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException argumentNullEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += argumentNullEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (SocketException socketEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += socketEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOperationEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += invalidOperationEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += ex.Message + "\n";
                }
            }));

        }

        private async void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string[] connectionStr = { "" };
            if (!textBoxServerIP.Text.Equals(null) && textBoxServerIP.Text != "")
            {
                connectionStr = textBoxServerIP.Text.Split(':');

                try
                {
                    hostname = connectionStr[0];
                    port = Int32.Parse(connectionStr[1]);
                    tcpClient = new TcpClient(connectionStr[0], Int32.Parse(connectionStr[1]));

                    //localDate = DateTime.Now;
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += "Connecting to server " + connectionStr[0] + "...\n";
                    if (tcpClient.Connected)
                    {
                        textBoxChatRoom.Text += "Connected!\n";
                        textBoxServerIP.IsEnabled = false;
                        textBoxNickname.IsEnabled = false;
                        buttonConnect.IsEnabled = false;
                        buttonDisconnect.IsEnabled = true;
                        localDate = DateTime.Now;

                        stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                        // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("new" + SEPERATOR + textBoxServerIP.Text.ToString() + SEPERATOR + textBoxNickname.Text.ToString());
                        if (stream.CanWrite)
                        {
                            await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        }

                        work = true;
                        worker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textBoxChatRoom.Text += "not connected!\n";
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException argumentNullExceptionEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += argumentNullExceptionEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException argumentOutOfRangeEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += argumentOutOfRangeEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (SocketException socketEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += socketEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (FormatException formatEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += formatEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (OverflowException overflowEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += overflowEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (CultureNotFoundException cultureNotFoundEx)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += cultureNotFoundEx.Message + "\n";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    textBoxChatRoom.Text += ex.Message + "\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxChatRoom.Text += "Please enter serverip!\n";
            }
        }


        private async void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            work = false;
            buttonConnect.IsEnabled = true;
            textBoxServerIP.IsEnabled = true;
            textBoxNickname.IsEnabled = true;
            buttonDisconnect.IsEnabled = false;

            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("close" + SEPERATOR + textBoxServerIP.Text.ToString() + SEPERATOR + textBoxNickname.Text.ToString());
            if (stream.CanWrite)
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            }

        }

        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private async void buttonSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("msg" + SEPERATOR + textBoxNickname.Text.ToString() + SEPERATOR + textBoxSend.Text);
                stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                if (stream.CanWrite)
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                }

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException argumentNullEx)
            {
                textBoxChatRoom.Text += argumentNullEx.Message + "\n";
            }
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                textBoxChatRoom.Text += socketEx.Message + "\n";
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOperationEx)
            {
                textBoxChatRoom.Text += invalidOperationEx.Message + "\n";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBoxChatRoom.Text += ex.Message + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The connection between server and clients functions but if I send something into the networkstream with one client, the other clients don't receive anything. This should be a little chatroom-WPF-application
I have a problem, that i couldn't receive and send between multiple clients and I don't know what I am doing wrong...
Please can somebody help...

Comment: Can You please narrow it down to a minimal example?

Comment: Clients are not receiving the data because you're not sending it to them. Restructure your server to hold up timestamps and messages, then store timestamp of the last sent packet for each client. Based on these timestamps resend missing messages.

Comment: based on the description, it would be better to use web socket...

Comment: how should i do this, could somebody write a functioning code, please....

Comment: You may be running into windows' built-in connection limitations. I have built a similar application, but my Windows 10 computer could only handle running the server and two clients simulataneously before running out of connections.